# Android: Many Buttons, one OnClickListener?

Tags: android, button, onclick

I"m currently working on an android application, and had a few questions.

1) In my app, there is a Battery Mod section. Their will be over 50 buttons for it. So, instead of doing something like:

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

  @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     Button buttonA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonA);    
     buttonA.setOnClickListener(this);
     Button buttonB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonB); 
     buttonB.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

//etc... etc...

public void onClick(View v) {

  switch (v.getId()) {
     case R.id.buttonA: 
      // do something
      break;
     case R.id.buttonB:
      // do something else
      break;
  }
}  
}
```

Is there a simpler way to do this? When you click the battery mod button,it will display an image of the mod, along with an option to install it. Other than the image, it'll be the same with each mod. If there isn't a simpler way.

Comment: If you want to make it a bit easier, you can specify android:onClick for the button in xml.  This will give a function that will be called when the button is clicked.  The function must be a member of Activity.  Easier than writing dozens of set calls.

Comment: Please split your question into two, so you can get specific answers for each one. Each post on SO should only have ONE question in it.

Comment: Your question should correspond to your title. You can ask multiple if they are closely related and still corresponds to title. But it seems like your second question doesn't.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't know that.

Comment: So you guys think it would be best for me to create a new question about the xml and classes?

Comment: You should Accept an answer if you find it helpful and solved your problem, then create a new question about the xml. Or do some research before you post it.

Answer (score 3):

One useful component to all Views that is not discussed much for this purpose is the tag attribute. You can set the View's tag to any Object:

```
Object foo = new Object();
button1.setTag(foo);
```

You can use this to easily assign tag to the name of the image, or perhaps the id of the `Drawable` resource. Then use one `onClick` method for all of these buttons, and simply unpack the tag to determine how it should be used:

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    //any button was clicked. Now determine what to do using the tag.

    Object tag = v.getTag();
    //TODO: use tag.


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could set the onClick callback of each button in the layout file. Something like:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/buttonText"
    android:onClick="onItemClick" />
```

Then, you add in your Activity/Fragment:

```
public void onItemClick(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button click
}
```

More information here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#HandlingEvents

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate through your buttons like so --

```
int[] buttons = { R.id.button1, R.id.button2, ... , R.id.button30 };

for( int i=0; i < buttons.length; i++ ) {
    final Button b = (Button) findViewById( buttons[ i ] );
    b.setOnClickListener( ... );
}
```

Comment: Ok. I'm still a little confused. Maybe I'm just a n00b. So you create a new integer called buttons, and then add the ids of the button within that. Then, you create a for loop. so while the integer i is less than the integer buttons's legnth, you'll add 1 to the int i. Then you create a button b that is equal to the buttons in the integer i, and then set an OnClickListener for this button. I just don't really understand how to use this.

Comment: The `[]` next to `int` means this is an array of integers. The for-loop walks through all the elements of the array, for each entry finding the `Button` and assigning the OnClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

What differs is the id. So you can't loop through that, and you will need to type it out like:

```
private static final BUTTON_IDS={R.id.buttonA,R.id.buttonB,R.id.buttonC....R.id.buttonZ};
```

then loop it:

```
    for(int i=0;i<BUTTON_IDS.lenght;i++{
        Button buttonXYZ = (Button) findViewById(BUTTON_IDS[i]);    
        buttonXYZ.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(...){
                        //your spical cases
                    }
                    else{
                        //do awesome generic stuff.
                    }

                    }
                });
    }
```